# Manifest has unsupported version: (we support )

Tags: dgraph, badgerdb

I am seeing  "Manifest has unsupported version: 4 (we support 7 )" on logs after updating my dgraph installation. What should I do? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are trying to run a version of [Dgraph](https://dgraph.io/) that uses a newer [Badger](https://github.com/dgraph-io/badger)( underlaying key-value storage) version than the one you are currently trying to initialize.

As of version 1.1, Dgraph lacks a self upgrading datastore mechanism so you will need to export and import all your data [as documented here](https://docs.dgraph.io/deploy/#upgrade-database).